# Does Database.QueryLocator and Iterable both have same limit?

Tags: apex, batch, big-object, iterable

I wrote a batch class to insert dummy data into big object and have used `Iterable` to insert data.
I was under impression that `Iterable` should only be able to insert in normal limit of 50K records.

But when I tried giving it 1 Millions, it processed even that. As this is the max I can insert in my developer edition.

Here is the sample :

```
global class BigObjectInsertHelper implements Database.Batchable<Integer> {

    global Iterable<Integer> start(Database.BatchableContext param1) {
        return new IntegerIterator(1000000);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext param1, List<Object> param2) {
        List<BigAccountRecord__b> bigAccountRecordBS = new List<BigAccountRecord__b>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < param2.size(); i++) {
            BigAccountRecord__b accountRecordB = new BigAccountRecord__b();
            accountRecordB.FirstName__c = 'Nagendra' + generateRandomString(5);
            accountRecordB.LastName__c = 'Nagendra' + generateRandomString(5);
            accountRecordB.Name__c = accountRecordB.FirstName__c + ' ' + accountRecordB.LastName__c;
            accountRecordB.PersonalEmail__c = generateRandomString(6) + '@gmail.' + generateRandomString(3);
            accountRecordB.Description__c = generateRandomString(40);
            bigAccountRecordBS.add(accountRecordB);
        }
        Database.insertImmediate(bigAccountRecordBS);
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext param1) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        // Replace IDs with valid record IDs in your org.
        message.toAddresses = new String[]{
                UserInfo.getUserEmail()
        };
        message.subject = 'Batch Status';
        message.plainTextBody = 'Finished with BigObject Insertion';
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages =
                new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{
                        message
                };
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
        if (results[0].success) {
            System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
        } else {
            System.debug('The email failed to send: ' + results[0].errors[0].message);
        }
    }

    public static String generateRandomString(Integer len) {
        final String chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        String randStr = '';
        while (randStr.length() < len) {
            Integer idx = Math.mod(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger()), chars.length());
            randStr += chars.substring(idx, idx + 1);
        }
        return randStr;
    }
}
```

Also, when I tried to pass `50 Million` / `60 Million` in my Iterable, it starts preparing the batch for it. But it never gives an error saying Maximum record limit reached.

[image]

Though it fails while preparing the batch, I think this is because there is a time limit in which `start` should return the result, `2 minutes` probably.

MY question is what is the limit of records which can be passed in `Iterable` in a batch class? Like we have for `QueryLocator` as 50 million max, do we have something for `Iterable` too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit for a QueryLocator is 50,000,000 records, the maximum size for any query (including API-based SOQL calls). The there is no hard limit for Iterable, though you're still limited by both CPU time (limit 60,000 ms/1 minute) and total start time (10 minutes); in practice, it might be hard to get up to even 50 million rows in that time, but it is likely theoretically possible.

In addition, Iterable return types have no hard maximum scope size, unlike QueryLocator, which will not allow more than 2,000 records per execute call. Other limits may limit how many items you can actually process (e.g. heap or CPU time), but there's no inherent hard limit for scope size.

Hypothetically speaking, using Iterable, you could process 100,000,000 items, or more, assuming you can somehow generate that many items in the time allotted.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know `Iterable` had unlimited scope size.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yeah, not sure if it's new or not, but I did doublecheck the documentation (was surprised to learn this myself, actually).

Comment: Would be pretty shocking if it's changed any time recently.

Comment: Does each start, execute and finish, all three have 2 minutes timeout. Or start and finish has 1 minute and execute has 2 minutes of timeout.

Comment: @NagendraSingh Every method has one minute (not two). However, time spent in callout and database doesn't count towards execution time limit. You can theoretically get up to 3 minutes of execution time with callouts.

Comment: So theoretically i can give a scope size of 100 and make internally hosted webservice call and do more processing and get a timeout increase of 3 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The only limit is what you can actually pass to it. At a certain point, you will hit a CPU timeout. If you try to query records and return the `List<SObject>` as your iterable, you will be confined to `Limits.getLimitQueryRows()`.